# Why is openssh-server needed to receive incoming ssh connections?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

Why is it needed? can't I just give an address:port and just "connect"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The TCP/IP network stack in the Linux kernel only provides a means for data transport: you need a program that listens to the incoming data, processes that, and sends output data back.  Such programs are usually called "servers" or "daemons"; that's why you need to run the "OpenSSH server" in order to *receive* SSH connections on your machine.

Answer (score 8):

The ssh connections to your computer are handled by an ssh server. If you do not have a server running then the connection request just gets ignored. Similarly: if you want to check a web page then the computer you are connecting to has to run an http server. In a default Ubuntu installation neither of these services are installed.

Comment: good to learn something thats a bit different than the topic ;)

Answer (score 1):

for more information about SSH protocols read this page :

[Open-Ssh Web Page](http://www.openssh.com/) and [help ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

*OpenSSH* server is not needed, but as Riccardo explains you will need **some** SSH server to accept the ssh connection and do something useful with it.  And if you don't have a good reason to use something else, using OpenSSH is a good idea (it's the best known & most used SSH server, and thus well-tested).

Answer (score 0):

On a side note. If you are just looking to setup something like a little test server, then you can use a program called netcat. It is available in the software center / synaptic, or can be downloaded at: http://netcat.sourceforge.net.

With this tool you can create a fake server.  Read some of the [examples here](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/06/netcat-a-couple-of-useful-examples/)

Keep in mind it isn't encrypted like SSH, this would just be for testing, I know it's a little off topic but figured it's useful information.